# How can I cap the MySQL query log size?

Tags: mysql, logging, query

I have Investigated enabling MySQL query logging. At some point, soon, it would be nice to enable this on my companies production server so that if there is ever a question about queries run against the database, we can see them.

I have found: 
Add the following line to /etc/my.cnf: 
log=/var/log/mysql_query.log and restart the MySQL server. 
I could also profile slow queries: 
log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log 
long_query_time = 1.

I have not yet found any documentation detailing log file size capping to ensure that the file does not continue to grow past a certain point. Is anyone aware of such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logrotate on linux to help with this.  There are many howtos that show you how to do this.  Essentially, make sure logrotate is in your crontab, I use the daily one on busy machines.

Then just create /etc/logrotate.d/mysql accordingly and you're off to the races!

Here's a great howto:

http://www.question-defense.com/2009/12/20/configure-logrotate-to-rotate-and-flush-mysql-logs-without-a-password